# Dynamics CRM SLA does not expire

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a custom SLA KPI called "Scope Check by" Although the failure time is computed correctly as per the configuration, the SLA counter doesn't stop and the status doesn't change to "Expired". [image]

The timer is configured correctly and out of the 10 SLA KPIs, only this one has this issue.

Comment: Did you try to delete & recreate?

Comment: yes, still doesnt work

Comment: Probably Microsoft support can assist you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. However I could not get a definitive answer as to why it happened. Two conditions in the Applicable When area had to be reorganized to merge a set together using AND like (X and Y) OR (X and Z). We also had to redo some workflows that we being triggered by fields set by failure action. Bottom line is you may look into 1. Applicable When and 2. Any workflows that are triggered by actions from SLA failure